# Find index of multiple keywords in given text file

Tags: java, c#, .net, full-text-search

I want to find the index/offset of a batch of keywords in a given text file.
Now, I've come across many questions on stackoverflow but answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33261565/2225030) one fits the best for me.

The only issue here is that above questions provide a solution for only a single keyword while I have more than 25 keywords to find & i think there has to be a better solution than to write `switch...case` or `if...else` for each keyword.

How can I optimize my task here? Any better approach other than the linked question is also welcome.

Let'say my text file has following content:

> Stephen Haren,December,9,4055551235
>
> Laura Clausing,January,23,4054447788
>
> William Connor,December,13,123456789
>
> Kara Marie,October,23,1593574862
>
> Audrey Carrit,January,16,1684527548
>
> Sebastian Baker,October,23,9184569876

And keywords i want to find are :

**December, January, March, April, May**

Now, the output should be:

> December : 16
>
> January : Overall Index of `January` in line 2
>
> December : Overall  Index of `January` in line 3
>
> ....

Current code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var keyword = "December";
            var keyword2 = "January";
            int totalLength = 0;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;
                    if (line.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("December: " + (totalLength + line.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
                    }
                    if (line.IndexOf(keyword2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("January: " + (totalLength + line.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
                    }
                    .................
                  ........................................................

                    totalLength += line.Length;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:**  Tagging `Java` here too as I am interested in approach rather than language-specific solution.

Comment: Please add to your question your inputs and expected outputs. Also, what did you try so far? Post your code.

Comment: Adding it. Give me a moment please.

Comment: Will also add the code

Comment: One approach is to convert the data of .txt file in to a datatable and then run query on the table with the search parameters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050112/how-to-read-a-csv-file-into-a-net-datatable

Comment: What is the value associated with this: `December : 16`? What is the number 16?

Comment: start-index of word `December` in first line

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks for the approach but my guess is that the sql query for that will kill the performance not to mention that i'll need to create another table to save the keywords which won't be possible.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1434177b-461f-430e-ab48-9c0ba1f52c0b/run-sql-query-on-datatable?forum=adodotnetdataset

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest you check out a Trie data structure.

A good implementation of Tries will search the input text character-by-character and returns whenever it reaches the end of a recognized word. It's extremely efficient i.t.o. runtime (approx O(n + m)) and not bad when it comes to memory consumption either. (FYI: In this case, n is the length of the input text and m is the length of the word you're looking for).

I found the following tutorial on the subject:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/

And here is a good implementation I found via [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416050/how-to-create-a-trie-in-c-sharp/6416341):

http://www.glennslayden.com/code/c-sharp/trie